# what are cached variables in autotools?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, build-system

Real example from irssi:

https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/master/configure.ac#L824

As everybody knows  autotools generates a `configure` script from a `configure.ac` file. In turn, the `configure.ac` file has number of `AC_ARG_WITH` and `AC_ARG_ENABLE` macros which afterwords define `--enable-foo` or `--with-foo` options that can be passed to the `configure` script.

In the example above libutf8proc support is being controlled via the `ac_cv_lib_utf8proc_utf8proc_version` option, and if you pass `export ac_cv_lib_utf8proc_utf8proc_version=no` to the current  env libutf8proc will be ignored during the configure phase.

The question is what are these variables for? Why not using standard configure macros? And the last one, is there a list of these variables somewhere documented or they all are being defined individually in the project>

Answer (score 1):

> The question is what are these variables for?

In the general sense, these variables are for remembering (caching) the results of checks performed via `configure`, so that it doesn't need to do them more than once.  You probably recall seeing the effect of that in `configure` output: whenever `configure` relies on a cached result instead of actually performing the test, it reports it in its output by annotating the result as "(cached)".  It is also possible to cache results in a file for re-use across `configure` runs.

In any case, these variables are set and used by various standard Autoconf macros, such as `AC_CHECK_LIBS` and the like.  Autoconf reserves shell variables whose names start with `ac_` or `AC_` for its own use.  You should not run a `configure` script in an environment that exports any such variables.

The Autoconf manual contains [more information](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Caching-Results.html) about caching.

> Why not using standard configure macros?

The particular example you present *is* using standard macros.  The variable in question is the one that reflects the result of this test that appears elsewhere in the project's `configure.ac`:

> ```
> AC_CHECK_LIB([utf8proc], [utf8proc_version])
> ```

If you want to retrieve the cached result of an Autoconf test then reading the value of the corresponding cache variable is the standard way to do so.  The variables adhere to a standard naming scheme to make that relatively easy.  That is, however, an uncommon thing to do.

> And the last one, is there a list of these variables somewhere documented or they all are being defined individually in the project>

The Autoconf manual documents those provided and used by Autoconf itself, and even has [an index devoted to them](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Cache-Variable-Index.html).  Individual projects can create their own, as well, but of course these won't be discussed in the Autoconf manual.

Answer (score 0):

the irssi maintainers decided, maybe erroneously, that libutf8proc does not need a configure switch (since it is optional to the functioning of the program, I presume)

autoconf will synthesise the cv variable name from this line

https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/c1b604ee6a810d8ac5959b4681c0f6da0f14fde3/configure.ac#L332

AC_CHECK_LIB([utf8proc], [utf8proc_version])